# React loadable server side rerendering and refetching when browser takes over

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, react-loadable

I have been trying to use react loadable library with Webpack 4.
On the SSR the page loaded correctly(all async import stuff loaded). 
However, the async components are gone for a split sec. 
react-loadable.json does not seems to have correct info since it does not fetch all the required chunks for the page(somehow shows correctly in server side). When I console.log chunks only few chunks shows up.
Could this because some route is dynamic?

Please look at attached screen shot below

Initiated by Script is the refetching part

[image]
Parse is happening in server side and script part happens in client side

**How I capture the required chunks from react-loadable.json**

```
  renderToString(
            <Provider store={store}>
              <StaticRouter location={urlPath} context={context}>
                <Loadable.Capture report={moduleName => {modules.push(moduleName)}}>
                  <AppRoot/>
                </Loadable.Capture>
              </StaticRouter>
            </Provider>
          )



console.log('last',  getBundles(stats, modules))
```

**Prod Server**

```
Loadable.preloadAll().then(() => {
  app.listen(PROD_PORT, (error) => {

  })
});
```

**Client side**

```
Loadable.preloadReady().then(() => {
    hydrate(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <AppRoot />
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>,
      domRoot,
    )
  })
```

**Split Chunks setup**

```
    styles: {
      name: 'styles',
      test: /\.css$/,
      chunks: 'all',
      enforce: true
    },
    vendors: {
      name: 'vendors',
      chunks: 'all',
      reuseExistingChunk: true,
      priority: 20,
      enforce: true,
      test(module, chunks) {
        const name = module.nameForCondition && module.nameForCondition();
        return chunks.some(chunk => {
          return chunk.name === 'main' && /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/.test(name);
        })
      }
    },
    common: {
      name: 'app.js',
      chunks: 'initial',
      test: /\.js$/,
      reuseExistingChunk: true,
    },
```

I would love to provide more info if it is necessary

Answer (score -1):

I think I had a similar issue with one of my projects. I think I solved it by wrapping the client side function like below

```
window.onload = () => { 
  Loadable.preloadReady().then(() => {
    hydrate(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <AppRoot />
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>,
      domRoot,
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: I cannot share repo its for work not my personal stuff .. I can share chunk of code not all repo for sure

Comment: No worries, I think I had a similar issue with one of my projects. I think I solved it by wrapping the client side function with window.onload = () => {}

Comment: Actually this approach cannot be used since it slow down meaningful paint by a lot a lot